# Android draw9patch: static area gone

Tags: android

I uploaded a screenshot what I'm doing: http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfoto0knmxp974g.png

I want the yellow area to be always the same size, whereas the transparent area at the top should scale. The problem is, that the whole image gets transparent with that configuration.

If I add another dot at the left side it works, but then the yellow area also scales...
If I understand the docs correctly, this should work as I thought.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding another row of transparent pixels on the top. Do the 9 patch on that.

Comment: gives the same result, even when the transparent area is as big as the yellow area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try un-marking the farthest right pixel along the top edge. I'm not exactly sure why this works, though.